# The qemu service libvirtd/virtqemud crashes with an "End of file while reading data: Input/output error"

Tags: qemu, libvirt

On my CentOS 9 Stream box my qemu service `libvirtd` or `virtgemud` crashes, tried both, not at the same time though ;-) (I'm aware I should use `virtgemud`)

I run fine between 5-300 seconds randomly :-/

The journal says:

[image]

Which file is it reading? I checked `/etc/hostname` but that seems to be fine?

UPDATE:
Did a file-open-read-trace of the `virtqemud` PID and it seems to fail on open/read these files: `/var/lib/sss/mc/passwd`, `/var/lib/sss/mc/group` which seems to belong to **System Security Services Daemon (SSSD)** (which I don't use or haven't installed).
Is this an mandatory QEMU dependency on RHEL'ish distros?
Never ran into this on Debian or OpenSUSE.

FYI my trace command: `strace -p 34123 -y -e trace=open,openat`